# Running Oracle NETCA/NETGMGR/DBCA on Docker for Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, user-interface, docker, dbca

I am trying to run dbca/netca commands on docker.

I already have Oracle 12c installed on docker, but I keep running into a issue.

When I run the `dbca` command, I get the error:

> DBCA cannot be run as root.

When I run the `netca` command, I get the error:

> Oracle Net Configuration Assistant cannot be run as root.

When I run the `netmgr` command, I get the error:

> Could not find the main class: oracle.net.mgr.container.NetApplication. Program will exit.

-netca/netmgr/dbca are all GUI tools managed by Oracle.

When I `sudo su - oracle` user, and I run the above commands, the docker/ system no longer even recognizes those commands.

See below:

```
oracle@6cc1eee63141:~$ dbca
-su: dbca: command not found
oracle@6cc1eee63141:~$ netca
-su: netca: command not found
oracle@6cc1eee63141:~$ netmgr
-su: netmgr: command not found
oracle@6cc1eee63141:~$ NETMGR
```

I have already exported my display to my computer IP address.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: add line   `export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin`  into `.bash_proflie` for oracle user

Comment: Hello Nyedidikeke - I added "export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin"  to the. profile, for oracle user but I am still having issues. Please clarify answer that you gave.

Comment: Check the environment variable  echo $ORACLE_HOME, if the variable is not set then  set the environment variable $ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Thanks that worked. When I try to run netca I get: "Could not find the main class: oracle.net.ca.NetCA.  Program will exit" I get the same error with netmgr

Comment: Any help will be appreciate :)